# In Resident Alien why does not alien Harry destroy the real Harry's body earlier?

Tags: resident-alien

In the Sy-fy television series *Resident Alien*, an alien ship crash lands on Earth, and the pilot alien realizes he has to stay on Earth for some time till he's able to fix the ship. Wandering around, he enters the cottage of a doctor named Harry Vanderspeigle near a lake (probably for shelter). He eventually kills Harry by throwing him to the freezing lake out of self defense when Harry tries to kill the alien. The alien then shapeshifts and assumes the physical appearance of Harry. The dead body of the real Harry is later washed ashore and the alien drags it into the cottage and hides it inside his freezer.

> It's only in the season finale episode he destroys the frozen dead body using an alien device that can decimate organic matter.

However, keeping a dead body in your freezer is very dangerous, as it's shown many times the town Sheriff and his Deputy are in constant alert because another murder has happened recently in the town nearby. This alien is depicted as from a smarter species than humans, and it's odd that he could not find a way to get rid of the body safely, for example using acid.

> It's noteworthy that the alien device is not functional till the penultimate episode of Season 1, but there are other ways to destroy a body and evidence

> One of the townspeople eventually finds out about the body when she opens the freezer, and the alien barely escapes by hiding the body in somewhere else when the Sheriff shows up in order to investigate.

So why not get rid of the body as soon as possible, instead of keeping it in the freezer and risking blowing his cover?

Comment: He learns English from Law & Order so he should have picked up some tips on disposal as well as the importance of disposal.